# How to install Horde Webmail on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, php

Am using Ubuntu 14.04. Am stuck with the following issue:

My goal is to install and have running **HORDER GROUPWARE 5.2** on my Domain/Hosting:

Download on Github: 
  https:// github .com/horde/horde/releases/tag/groupware-5.2.2

Installation on Github: 
 https://github.com/horde/horde/tree/master/bundles/groupware

Demo: 
 http://demo.horde.org/

> ## Quick Install
>
> These are very terse instructions how to install Horde Groupware and
>   its prerequisites on a LAMP sytem. They are addressed to experienced
>   administrators who know exactly what they are doing.  For more
>   detailed instructions, start reading below at Prerequisites_.
>
> 1. Compiling PHP for Apache 2::
>
>    cd php-x.x.x/
>       ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs2 \
>                   --with-gettext --enable-mbstring=all --enable-mbregex \
>                   --with-gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
>                   [--with-mysql|--with-pgsql|--with-oci8]
>                   [--with-tidy]
>                   [--with-ftp]
>       make
>       make install
>
> ## Can't even start with this method couse there is not such "php-x.x.x" folder on my ubuntu root, and there is not such think on internet called "compiling php for apache2". Any idea?
>
> 2. Restart Apache.
> 3. Register Horde PEAR channel::
>
>    pear channel-discover pear.horde.org
> 4. Set Horde installation directory::
>
>    pear install horde/horde_role
>       pear run-scripts horde/horde_role
> 5. Install Horde Groupware::
>
>    pear install -a -B horde/groupware
> 6. Run installation script::
>
>    groupware-install
> 7. Test Horde Groupware::
>
>    http:// your-server /horde/test.php

So I try to install it with the other way that is explained on the INSTALLATION guide:

> ## Prerequisites
>
> The following prerequisites are **REQUIRED** for Horde Groupware to
>   function properly.
>
> 1. A webserver that supports PHP.
>
>    Horde Groupware is primarily developed under the Apache and
>      Lighttpd    webservers, which we recommend.  These servers are
>      available from:
>
>    http:// httpd.apache .org/
>        http:// www.lighttpd .net/
>
> **(MY NOTE: i use Apache 2 I have LAMP already installed and functioning well on my OS)**
>
> ## OK! Done,
>
> 2. A web server with PATH_INFO support.
>
>    The dynamic interfaces of Horde Groupware requires a web server
>      that    correctly sets the PATH_INFO environment variable for all PHP
>      scripts. Every    modern web server supports this, but you might have
>      to enable this feature    in the web server configuration.  e.g.
>      Apache servers require::
>
>    AcceptPathInfo On
>
>    Lighttpd servers require::
>
>    "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
>
> ## Can't continue from this point couse I can't find on internet "How to config the web server apache and change AcceptPathInfo to ON,
>
> 3. PHP 5.3.0 or above.
>
>    PHP is the interpreted language in which Horde Groupware is
>      written.
>
>    .. Note:: If possible, you should install PHP with your operating
>      system's
>               package manager. Alternatively you build PHP yourself.
>
>    To build PHP from sources, you can obtain it at
>
>    http:// www.php .net/
>
>    Follow the instructions in the PHP package to build PHP for your
>      one of the following    options::
>      system. If    you use Apache, be sure to build PHP as a library with
>
>    --with-apache
>         --with-apxs
>         --with-apxs2
>
> **etc, etc, etc more on the INSTALLATION link.**

Any idea on how to keep installing it? there is no resources on internet (videos, or tutorials) on how to install it in a different way or somethink, only for older versions like **HORDER GROUPWARE 1.2** but this is really old software, what am trying to install is the 5.2

Do you have expirience with this issues?
Any guidance is apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this excellent how-to for the setup of a complete mail/groupware solution based on Horde Webmail. It ist written for Ubuntu 12.04 but works on 14.04 also:

https://www.exratione.com/2012/05/a-mailserver-on-ubuntu-1204-postfix-dovecot-mysql/

See 19) for the Horde Webmail installation.

> Author: Reason
>
> Horde 5 is a groupware framework that includes applications focused on
>   webmail. Putting it in place is a mix of apt-get and PECL / Pear
>   package installations, much of which I lifted from the Ubuntu guide
>   for Horde 4 and then adapted to this server setup. The first step is
>   to install as many of the needed packages as possible through apt-get:
>
> ```
> apt-get install php5-dev php5-sasl php-pear php5-tidy php5-imagick 
> apt-get install php5-geoip libgeoip1 geoip-bin geoip-database
> apt-get install php-xml-serializer php5-memcache php-soap php5-intl
> apt-get install libidn11-dev libmagickwand-dev libmagick++4 imagemagick
> apt-get install libsasl2-dev libssh2-php libphp-jpgraph php-http-webdav-server
> ```
>
> Next update the PECL and Pear package managers and install the
>   remaining required packages:
>
> ```
> pecl channel-update pear.php.net
> pear channel-update pear.php.net
> pecl install lzf
> pear install --alldeps channel://pear.php.net/Date_Holidays-0.21.5
> pear install --alldeps channel://pear.php.net/Date_Holidays_UNO-0.1.3
> pear install --alldeps channel://pear.php.net/Date_Holidays_USA-0.1.1
> pear install --alldeps channel://pear.php.net/Numbers_Words-0.16.2
> pear install --alldeps channel://pear.php.net/Text_CAPTCHA-0.4.3
> ```
>
> Next up is installing the Horde components. Start with these commands:
>
> ```
> pear channel-discover pear.horde.org
> pear install horde/Horde_role
> pear run-scripts horde/Horde_role
> ```
>
> At this point, you will be prompted to enter the "Filesystem location
>   for the base Horde application" - so enter the full path to your
>   webroot without a trailing slash, i.e. /var/www. Next, start the
>   installation process with the command below. This will take a while to
>   run to completion:
>
> ```
> pear install -a -B horde/webmail
> ```
>
> At this point it is a good idea to make sure that all of your PHP
>   extensions are in fact enabled. Some may not be; the following
>   commands ensure that the configuration files that were missing in my
>   installation trial run are created, and then restart Apache to pick
>   them up:
>
> ```
> echo "extension=memcache.so" > /etc/php5/conf.d/memcache.ini
> echo "extension=lzf.so" > /etc/php5/conf.d/lzf.ini
> service apache2 restart
> ```
>
> The Horde application will now be sitting in your webroot, but owned
>   by root. So change the ownership to the Apache user:
>
> ```
> chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www The installation will have overwritten /var/www/.htaccess, so edit that file to reinstate your
> ```
>
> mod_rewrite rule that redirects all traffic to HTTPS. It will look
>   much like this:
>
> ```
> allow from all
>
> <ifmodule mod_rewrite.c="">
>     RewriteEngine On
>
>     # Add the redirect to HTTPS rule.
>     RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
>     RewriteRule ^(.*) https://mail.example.com/$1 [L]
>
>     # This is the default Horde rule.
>     RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
>     RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
>     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rampage.php [QSA,L]
> </ifmodule>
> ```
>
> Once Horde is running it is completely open to the world in order to
>   allow initial configuration. So first lock it down to be accessible
>   from your IP address only - at least until you have an administrator
>   and authentication set up. Do that by making this change to the
>   /var/www/.htaccess file - in the example below replace 10.10.10.10
>   with the IP address you are using:
>
> ```
> #allow from all
>
> # Remove this block when done
> Order deny,allow
> deny from all
> allow from 10.10.10.10
> allow from 127.0.0.1
> ```
>
> You can check to see that all of the required and/or desired PHP
>   extensions are installed and working by visiting
>   http://mail.example.com/test.php in your browser. It will provide a
>   list of what is and is not presently installed. This guide leaves out
>   LDAP and PAM support in PHP, for example, as they are not needed here.
>
> Now log in to MySQL as root:
>
> ```
> mysql -uroot -p You will need to create a MySQL database for Horde:
>
> create database horde;
> grant all on horde.* to 'horde'@'localhost' identified by 'hordepassword';
> ```